# How to get second value from string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string with comma now I want to get first value. How can I get it?

My Code:-

```js
var data = "0.46609362959861755, 0.25069287419319153, 0.5107838958501816, 0.26014574989676476";

console.log(data.replaceAll(',','').splice(0,2));
```

Comment: Why not split it first?

Comment: second value or first value? and I think you want [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need this?

```js
data.split(',')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(data.split(', ')[0])
```

Use this instead of what you did.

```
data.split(', ')
```

returns an array with every element in your string, separately, with no spaces or commas attached. The [0] after it grabs the first element of the array.